# Discord Embeds align name andd value in fields in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So im trying to create a discord embed display that will look like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwMiq.png)
But i don't know how to align the name and the value of the fields
is there a possible way to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can just use newlines in the value. I've recreated the embed you showed, hope that helps!

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.add_field(name="Ranked stats for RANKED_SOLO_5x5:",
                    value="**➤ Rank:** `SILVER I`\n**➤ Wins:** 25\n**➤ Losses:** 22\n**➤ LP:** 5", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Ranked stats for RANKED_FLEX_SR:",
                    value="**➤ Rank:** `SILVER IV`\n**➤ Wins:** 78\n**➤ Losses:** 86\n**➤ LP:** 25", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Thresh", value="**➤ Name:** `Thresh`\n**➤ Level:** 7\n**➤ Points:** 61074", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Blitzcrank", value="**➤ Name:** `Blitzcrank`\n**➤ Level:** 7\n**➤ Points:** 53040",
                    inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Senna", value="**➤ Name:** `Senna`\n**➤ Level:** 5\n**➤ Points:** 24526", inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

[image: embed]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help