# How do I add an embed field below another embed field instead of it going to the right

Tags: discord.py

Hi im wondering if theres anyway to make a discord embed field go below another discord embed field instead of going to the right without filling the right embed fields with invisible characters.

[what im trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRBk3.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Jason! The next time you ask a question, please ensure to add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well as what you have already tried so it's easier for others to help you. Happy coding!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`discord.Embed.add_field`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=add_field#discord.Embed.add_field) takes in three arguments; `name`, `value` and `inline`. By default, all fields have `inline` set to `True`, causing the fields to be placed next to each other. Therefore, you will want to specify otherwise. This can be done easily, as seen in the code and image below.

```py
# 'Create' embed
embed = discord.Embed(title="Embed Title")
# Add embed fields
embed.add_field(name="Field 1", value="Value 1", inline=False)
embed.add_field(name="Field 2", value="Value 2", inline=False)
embed.add_field(name="Field 3", value="Value 3", inline=False)
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

[image: Working image]

**Other Links**:

- [`discord.Embed`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed) - Discord.py Docs
- [How to align fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212859/how-to-align-fields-in-discord-py-embedded-messages) - Stackoverflow
- [Discord Embeds align name and value in fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63509154/discord-embeds-align-name-andd-value-in-fields-in-discord-py) - Stackoverflow